# using a where clause with a left join

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

```
USER:
id  name
1   John
2   Cian
3   Una

ATTR:
id name           value      user_id
1  LAST_LOGGED_IN 2016-10-10 1
1  ADDED          2015-01-01 1
1  ADDED          2015-01-01 2
```

and wish to produce this:

```
user_id user_name last_logged_in added 
1       John      2016-10-10     2015-01-01
2       Cian      NULL           2015-01-01
3       Una       NULL           NULL
```

My attempt is:

```
select USER.NAME, ATTR.VALUE as LAST_LOGGED_IN 
from USER 
left join ATTR on USER.ID = ATTR.USER_ID
where ATTR.NAME = "LAST_LOGGED_IN"
GROUP BY USER.NAME;
```

but it is not correct.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, inclusion of a GROUP BY clause is generally a bad idea. That said, you probably *do* want an aggregating function!!

Answer (score -1):

```
select  USER.NAME,  IF(ATTR.NAME = 'LAST_LOGGED_IN',ATTR.VALUE,NULL) as LAST_LOGIN 
from USER 
right join ATTR on USER.ID = ATTR.USER_ID 
GROUP BY USER.ID;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.